# xzcat version XZ_5.2 not found

Tags: buildroot, xz

I'm getting the following error when running buildroot on a project that is working for other developers in my group. I get the same error if I run `xz --version`.

`xzcat: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5: version 'XZ_5.2' not found (required by xzcat)`

Comment: "version 'XZ_5.2' not found" is sign of version mismatch between xzcat / xz utility and liblzma.so library. Probably library is older than xz tool.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by installing xz stable release 5.2.3 (2016-12-30).

Thanks to instructions from here, plus ldconfig:
https://blog.csdn.net/xhoufei2010/article/details/51280249

Summary of steps:

Download and extract xz-5.2.3.tar.gz from http://tukaani.org/xz/

```
cd xz-5.2.3
./configure --enable-shared
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: This issue may have been introduced by Anaconda, according to this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/864584/how-can-i-update-xz-utils-system-wide-after-building-from-source